# In Dungeon Run, is there ever a reason to assist another player if you have full health?

Tags: tactics, cooperation, dungeon-run

In Dungeon Run, when another player is on your tile, you can assist them. If you do, you are allowed to rally which means to remove a single damage from your character.

Since any other player will eventually be an opponent, does it make any tactical or strategic sense to assist them if you don't get a benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of situations where assisting another player without being able to rally might be beneficial to you.

- **If not doing so will most likely lose you the game** - If an opponent has the summoning stone, and is rolling many more dice than another player, it may be useful to help that player damage the summoner. You will most likely be wounding your opponents, with no possibility of hurting yourself. If you cannot do enough damage by yourself or others to kill the summoner, then you will have no chance of winning the game without getting the bonus dice from assisting.
- **If another player is out of Actions and a Monster has a treasure** - The monster will drop the treasure, and you will be able to pick it up during your turn (thanks to the other player).

Answer (score 5):

Sure.  There are several reasons you might want to do this.  Obviously if there's a monster that will threaten you, and you're worried about it, and your opponent can't kill him on his own, you may want to assist.

On a more strategic level, you may want to cooperate, especially if there are more than 2 players.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tit_for_tat for a game theory perspective on building trust.  If you and another player are cooperating, you both get a benefit relative to the other players (as the next time he'll assist you, even if he doesn't have damage).

Comment: +1 for important general theory.  Even in purely-competitive games, if there are more than two players then any two who cooperate have an advantage over all people who don't.

Comment: @Tynam, General Theory is great an all, except when it doesn't apply. Tit for Tat works in a non-zero-sum game which is played over a period of time, and it works because both parties win more by cooperating. Without receiving a free rally, I don't know if this intangible "trust" will help you level up faster, or remove the Summoning Stone from the dungeon. If I help someone else defeat a monster, I actually only benefit that player relative to other players including myself. That player is half way to leveling up, if I help them escape I cannot receive help to escape myself.

Comment: @user1873: Your comment is correct, but only if you're only playing once.  If you and another player are cooperating well over multiple games - even when it doesn't help you in one game - then the trust advantage lets you *both* win more games than others who don't cooperate.  In Dungeon Run this is a small consideration, but it's not quite zero.  (As you correctly say in your answer, in a single game the only real reason is to help remove a monster, or winning player, that you want gone.)